# Why does this not return an error?

Tags: function, python-2.7, error-handling

I'm trying to evaluate arbitrary strings to know whether they are valid Python function definitions.

I ran this test at first :

```
i1 = "def z(a): return a"
exec(i1)
i2 = "def z(a): eturn a"
exec(i2)
```

Which raises a SyntaxError for i2. Then i tried with the real values I'm gonna have to evaluate :

```
i3 = """def fct_lambda(s,x):
    return lambmax*(x>xmin)"""
exec(i3)
i4 = """def fct_lambda(s,x):
    eturn lambmax*(x>xmin)"""
exec(i4)
```

Which yields SyntaxError for i4, seems ok. But then i came to the point :

```
i5 = """def densite_initiale(x):
    return (((((x-0.0005)/0.00025)*(1-(x-0.0005)/0.00025))**5)*(x>0.0005)*(x<0.00075))"""
exec(i5)
i6 = """def densite_initiale(x):
    eturn (((((x-0.0005)/0.00025)*(1-(x-0.0005)/0.00025))**5)*(x>0.0005)*(x<0.00075))"""
exec(i6)
```

Which yields no error for i6. However, if I delete a single parenthesis I will get a SyntaxError sent back, but not for the `eturn` NameError.

Additionally, is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: Going for an exec("densite_initiale(99)") actually yields the NameError, but I am not able to do that because there might be other variables out of my current scope in the definitions (like xmin for fct_lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eturn(insert_expression_here)` isn't a syntax error. The interpreter assumes you're calling a method called `eturn` with the arguments inside the parentheses. Sure, that function doesn't exist, but the interpreter won't complain until you actually execute `densite_initiale`.

Comment: Because they aren't in the form `eturn(insert expression here)`. They don't have parentheses following them. i6 has the form `identifier(expression)`, whereas i2 and i4 are of the form `identifier identifier` and `identifier identifier*(expression)`. The first one is valid syntax, and the latter two aren't.